# Restarting Previous Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a new journey version and activated it. I have found an issue and want to resume the previous version, which is in finishing mode. How do make the previous version active again? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2382031 It is not possible to restart the previous version of journey.

When you activate the new version of the journey, contacts in the previous version will exit the journey automatically after flowing through all the activities and the new contacts who qualify will enter into the new version.

Salesforce document link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_versions.htm&type=5

Comment: thank you for the response